# Dimensional Tolerance for US Standard NEMA 1-15 Plugs

Tags: connector, standard

I am trying to find the dimensional tolerance on US electrical plugs. I have tried looking online, but I have only been able to find that they are called [NEMA 1-15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEMA_connector#NEMA_1), and have found the picture below showing length and height for the male connector (but not width of the *male* prong), and I haven't been able to find dimensional **tolerances** anywhere.

[image: NEMA 1-15 Plug Dimensions]

I ask here because I'm assuming there's a US code that governs electrical plugs, but I can't seem to find the standard anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the dimensions in [ANSI/NEMA WD 6](http://www.nema.org/Standards/ComplimentaryDocuments/NEMA%20WD%206%20-%20Non-Locking%20Plugs%20and%20Receptacles%20-%20Excerpt.pdf). The standard costs money, but the free excerpt (linked above) will probably suit your purposes:

[image]

Dimensions are in inches, of course.